# i just want to view my records from my database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

simply I am trying to make a database for students, but when I request the view records page it doesn't work giving me an error, why doesn't it work I just want to view my records from my database

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use DB;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 class StudViewController extends Controller {
 public function index(){
 /*$users = DB::select('select * from tudent');*/
 $users = DB::table('student')->select(DB::raw('*'))->get();
 return view('stud_view',['users'=>$users]);
  }
  }
```

this is the view

```
      <html>

       <head>
       <title>View Student Records</title>
      </head>

        <body>
      <table border = 1>
     <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
     </tr>
      @foreach ($users as $user)
     <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
       </tr>
       @endforeach
      </table>

     </body>
     </html>
```

this is the Route

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
     });

     // ----------- insert student --------------
       Route::get('insert','StudInsertController@insertform');
       Route::post('create','StudInsertController@insert');

    // ----------- view Record --------------
       Route::get('view-records','StudViewController@index');
```

Comment: add code in your question instead of images and show error

Comment: If you can add the code to the question it's much more helpful, and also add the error you are getting

Comment: show what `dd($users)` gives

Comment: add `dd($users)` after database query in controller and show us result and also follow my first comment

Comment: you can change your query to this `$users = DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw('*'))->get();`

Comment: i have updated my code

Comment: @Sohel0415 

i have changed the view code but still give me error in the view in line 15 which is
    foreach ($users as $user)
     <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
       </tr>
       endforeach

Comment: in your view try this `$student['id']`

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all you should make your code more readable by respecting coding indentation and variables naming
2. Second, you can use the Student model to get all the students in DB. No need to use the DB facade
3. There is no need to create 2 controllers `StudViewController` and `StudInsertController` to manipulate students data, but you should create an single controller named `StudentController`. Inside this controller you can have multiple actions: `index`, `create`, `update`, etc. The routes would be:

   ```
   Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
   });

   // ----------- insert student --------------
   Route::get('create','StudentController@create');
   Route::post('store','StudentController@store');

   // ----------- list students --------------
   Route::get('list','StudentController@index');
   ```

---

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Student;

class StudViewController extends Controller
{
     public function index()
     {
          $students = Student::all();

          return view('stud_view', ['students' => $students]);
     }
}
```

In `stud_view` view you access the students like you already did:

```
@foreach ($students as $student)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $student->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Collection {#173 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#174 ▼
      +"ID": 1
      +"Name": "hassan"
    }
    1 => {#176 ▼
      +"ID": 2
      +"Name": "Ahmed"
    }
    2 => {#177 ▼
      +"ID": 3
      +"Name": "7oms"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: i don't want to see this

Comment: that's because you used `dd` function somewhere.. you should remove that function call

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
        if(Session::has('adminSession')){
          //$users = User::paginate(2);
       //  $users=User::Where('admin','=','')->get();
          $users = User::where(['admin' => null])->get();        
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($users);die;

         return view('admin.users.users',compact('users'));
        }else{
          return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message_error','Please login to access');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function index(){
 /*$users = DB::select('select * from tudent');*/
 $users = DB::table('student')->select(DB::raw('*'))->get();
 dd($users);
 return view('stud_view',['users'=>$users]);
}
```

Comment: array:3 [▼
  0 => {#172 ▶}
  1 => {#174 ▶}
  2 => {#175 ▶}
]

it give me this

Comment: what is the meaning of " dd($users); "

Comment: dd like var_dump